# long table in landscape environment

Tags: page-numbering, longtable, landscape

I am trying to insert a longtable in the landscape environment. Following some Google queries I found this stack overflow question ["How do I make multi page landscape tables in LaTeX"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2717285/how-do-i-make-multi-page-landscape-tables-in-latex).

I followed their code however now in the output PDF only the last page of the longtable is rotated in the PDF (so you have to tilt your head to see the first 2 pages of the longtable. I would like all the pages to be rotated like page three in the pdf output. Here is the code (sorry its pretty long!)

```
\documentclass[pdftex, a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{longtable}
\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}
\label{tab_rf_ff}
\centering     % optional, probably makes it look better to have it centered on the page
\begin{longtable}{p{1.5cm} |  rrrr | p{2cm} p{2cm} r | p{2cm} p{2cm}r | rr}
\hline
Model number & mtry & node.size & ntree & replace & Mean test RMSE & Median test RMSE & SE & Mean OOB RMSE & median OOB RMSE & SE & Median leaf \\ 
  \hline
 43 &   2 &  20 & 500 &   0 & 50.13 & 34.25 & 2.88 & 65.24 & 71.54 & 1.06 &  16 \\ 
   52 &   2 &  20 & 750 &   0 & 50.15 & 34.73 & 2.88 & 65.23 & 71.51 & 1.06 &  16 \\ 
   34 &   2 &  20 & 250 &   0 & 50.19 & 34.64 & 2.88 & 65.28 & 71.51 & 1.06 &  16 \\ 
    7 &   2 &  20 & 250 &   1 & 50.64 & 35.02 & 2.85 & 65.55 & 71.81 & 1.06 &  25 \\ 
   25 &   2 &  20 & 750 &   1 & 50.67 & 35.11 & 2.85 & 65.49 & 71.91 & 1.06 &  25 \\ 
   16 &   2 &  20 & 500 &   1 & 50.69 & 34.97 & 2.85 & 65.51 & 71.69 & 1.06 &  25 \\ 
   53 &   4 &  20 & 750 &   0 & 51.16 & 35.92 & 2.83 & 65.82 & 72.16 & 1.07 &  16 \\ 
   35 &   4 &  20 & 250 &   0 & 51.18 & 36.14 & 2.83 & 65.88 & 72.14 & 1.07 &  16 \\ 
   44 &   4 &  20 & 500 &   0 & 51.20 & 35.70 & 2.83 & 65.84 & 72.09 & 1.07 &  16 \\ 
   40 &   2 &   5 & 500 &   0 & 51.62 & 36.80 & 2.80 & 66.02 & 72.32 & 1.07 &  77 \\ 
   31 &   2 &   5 & 250 &   0 & 51.69 & 37.28 & 2.80 & 66.14 & 72.53 & 1.08 &  77 \\ 
   49 &   2 &   5 & 750 &   0 & 51.72 & 36.51 & 2.79 & 66.01 & 72.25 & 1.07 &  77 \\ 
   17 &   4 &  20 & 500 &   1 & 51.95 & 37.35 & 2.79 & 66.28 & 72.63 & 1.07 &  25 \\ 
   26 &   4 &  20 & 750 &   1 & 52.03 & 37.08 & 2.78 & 66.26 & 72.64 & 1.07 &  25 \\ 
   13 &   2 &   5 & 500 &   1 & 52.09 & 37.20 & 2.77 & 66.31 & 72.51 & 1.07 & 107 \\ 
   22 &   2 &   5 & 750 &   1 & 52.09 & 36.71 & 2.77 & 66.23 & 72.45 & 1.07 & 107 \\ 
    4 &   2 &   5 & 250 &   1 & 52.09 & 37.12 & 2.78 & 66.38 & 72.56 & 1.07 & 107 \\ 
    8 &   4 &  20 & 250 &   1 & 52.18 & 36.92 & 2.77 & 66.43 & 72.71 & 1.08 &  25 \\ 
   10 &   2 &   1 & 500 &   1 & 52.45 & 38.30 & 2.76 & 66.57 & 72.96 & 1.07 & 171 \\ 
   46 &   2 &   1 & 750 &   0 & 52.47 & 38.41 & 2.77 & 66.56 & 72.85 & 1.08 & 171 \\ 
   19 &   2 &   1 & 750 &   1 & 52.49 & 38.20 & 2.76 & 66.53 & 72.79 & 1.07 & 171 \\ 
   37 &   2 &   1 & 500 &   0 & 52.57 & 38.38 & 2.76 & 66.59 & 72.90 & 1.07 & 171 \\ 
    1 &   2 &   1 & 250 &   1 & 52.64 & 37.79 & 2.75 & 66.77 & 73.19 & 1.08 & 171 \\ 
   28 &   2 &   1 & 250 &   0 & 52.74 & 38.40 & 2.74 & 66.79 & 73.17 & 1.08 & 171 \\ 
   45 &   9 &  20 & 500 &   0 & 52.91 & 38.77 & 2.74 & 66.98 & 73.49 & 1.11 &  16 \\ 
   36 &   9 &  20 & 250 &   0 & 53.05 & 39.53 & 2.74 & 67.05 & 73.44 & 1.11 &  16 \\ 
   54 &   9 &  20 & 750 &   0 & 53.05 & 39.04 & 2.74 & 66.98 & 73.34 & 1.11 &  16 \\ 
   50 &   4 &   5 & 750 &   0 & 53.38 & 39.36 & 2.73 & 67.12 & 73.53 & 1.09 &  77 \\ 
   32 &   4 &   5 & 250 &   0 & 53.42 & 39.22 & 2.72 & 67.21 & 73.50 & 1.10 &  77 \\ 
   41 &   4 &   5 & 500 &   0 & 53.49 & 39.62 & 2.72 & 67.13 & 73.31 & 1.09 &  77 \\ 
   27 &   9 &  20 & 750 &   1 & 53.91 & 40.12 & 2.72 & 67.59 & 73.89 & 1.09 &  25 \\ 
   18 &   9 &  20 & 500 &   1 & 53.93 & 39.87 & 2.72 & 67.62 & 74.03 & 1.09 &  25 \\ 
    9 &   9 &  20 & 250 &   1 & 53.97 & 40.51 & 2.72 & 67.73 & 74.08 & 1.09 &  25 \\ 
    5 &   4 &   5 & 250 &   1 & 54.01 & 40.31 & 2.69 & 67.59 & 74.20 & 1.10 & 104 \\ 
   23 &   4 &   5 & 750 &   1 & 54.03 & 39.52 & 2.68 & 67.38 & 73.79 & 1.10 & 104 \\ 
   14 &   4 &   5 & 500 &   1 & 54.14 & 40.62 & 2.68 & 67.47 & 73.87 & 1.10 & 104 \\ 
    2 &   4 &   1 & 250 &   1 & 54.46 & 40.57 & 2.68 & 68.08 & 74.31 & 1.10 & 169 \\ 
   20 &   4 &   1 & 750 &   1 & 54.48 & 40.76 & 2.67 & 67.78 & 74.08 & 1.10 & 170 \\ 
   47 &   4 &   1 & 750 &   0 & 54.48 & 41.27 & 2.69 & 67.92 & 74.29 & 1.10 & 169 \\ 
   38 &   4 &   1 & 500 &   0 & 54.54 & 40.62 & 2.68 & 68.02 & 74.46 & 1.10 & 169 \\ 
   11 &   4 &   1 & 500 &   1 & 54.54 & 39.86 & 2.67 & 67.83 & 74.07 & 1.10 & 169 \\ 
   29 &   4 &   1 & 250 &   0 & 54.72 & 41.83 & 2.66 & 68.15 & 74.04 & 1.10 & 169 \\ 
   33 &   9 &   5 & 250 &   0 & 55.13 & 42.88 & 2.69 & 68.69 & 74.69 & 1.09 &  76 \\ 
   51 &   9 &   5 & 750 &   0 & 55.15 & 43.81 & 2.68 & 68.45 & 74.63 & 1.10 &  76 \\ 
   42 &   9 &   5 & 500 &   0 & 55.40 & 43.78 & 2.67 & 68.65 & 74.95 & 1.10 &  76 \\ 
   24 &   9 &   5 & 750 &   1 & 55.77 & 44.96 & 2.65 & 68.85 & 75.22 & 1.11 & 101 \\ 
   15 &   9 &   5 & 500 &   1 & 55.89 & 44.75 & 2.64 & 68.89 & 75.11 & 1.11 & 101 \\ 
    6 &   9 &   5 & 250 &   1 & 55.98 & 44.66 & 2.64 & 69.07 & 75.36 & 1.12 & 101 \\ 
   21 &   9 &   1 & 750 &   1 & 56.33 & 46.81 & 2.63 & 69.46 & 75.48 & 1.12 & 162 \\ 
   48 &   9 &   1 & 750 &   0 & 56.33 & 46.41 & 2.65 & 69.63 & 75.49 & 1.11 & 161 \\ 
   12 &   9 &   1 & 500 &   1 & 56.37 & 45.51 & 2.64 & 69.48 & 75.57 & 1.13 & 162 \\ 
   30 &   9 &   1 & 250 &   0 & 56.49 & 46.09 & 2.64 & 69.91 & 75.55 & 1.12 & 161 \\ 
    3 &   9 &   1 & 250 &   1 & 56.49 & 46.31 & 2.62 & 69.70 & 75.46 & 1.13 & 162 \\ 
   39 &   9 &   1 & 500 &   0 & 56.65 & 47.81 & 2.64 & 69.78 & 75.96 & 1.13 & 161 \\ 
   \hline
\caption{Accuracy results for forest fires random forest}
\end{longtable}
\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

Also how can I get the page numbers to appear in the correct place on landscape pages?

Answer (score 8):

If using pdflatex you may prefer `pdflscape` to the `lscape` package, which inserts some extra instructions to the pdf viewer. (note that pdf viewers often auto-rotate pages to get what they think is the correct reading orientation and they don't always get this right)   You ask how to get the page numbers in the right place, but you don't say where that place is. lscape puts them where it (I) thought was right.

Comment: Thank you the pdflscape package has given me exactly what I wanted! Currently my page numbers are appearing in the 'correct' place with the portrait pages of the document (bottom short edge of page). But the landscape pages are numbered on the left short edge, when I want them on the bottom long edge.

Comment: ah well lscape goes to some lengths not to do that:-) for online reading it would probably make sense to rotate all the content but in traditional book printing the page head and foot stay where they are and just the content moves. You would have to hook the rotation into a different place to do that, so essentially replace all of lscape with something similar but different. Someone may offer something but I'm out of time to look at that during the day.